# How do you work with closing pools/connections?

Tags: database, npm, mariadb

I wanted to know when you are done processing some query or transaction do you usually close a connection only? do you close the pool? or do you close both? Does it even matter which one you close? What happens under the hood when you do all three of these cases (if there even is a difference). I’d appreciate it since I’ve been looking at the mariadb documentation and I see there are methods for closing both a pool and a connection and usually you instantiate opening one connection in the pool as far as I know and you need to close it when you are done using it.

https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/promise-api.md#promise-api

I’d appreciate the guidance! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd "close" (or release) the Connection - the Pool maintains a list of Connections for your application to use (FIFO queuing the request if no Connection is available). It's semantic - but technically you don't actually close the connection; you release it back to the pool:

```
const pool = mariadb.createPool({ host: 'mydb.com', user:'myUser' });
pool.getConnection()
   .then(conn => {
     console.log("connected");
     conn.release(); //release NOT close
   })
   .catch(console.error);
```

Closing the Pool using `pool.end()` will gracefully close all open Connections (not just the current). You'd need to recreate the Pool to get another Connection.

Comment: Thank You for the response! Just one more question Is there a reason to .end() a connection or when you need to forcefully shut down a connection .destroy()? In what situation would we want to .close() a pool? Seems like .release() gets the job done when using it on a api endpoint.

Comment: `.release()` will return connection back to the pool, AFAIK `.end()` will do the same - I assume you'd use it if you've manually created the connection as opposed to retrieving it from the pool.  I would use `pool.close()` usually when gracefully shutting down a service.

Comment: Got it! Thank You very much! 